# How to extract/rip audio contents of an .exe?

Tags: macos, applications, resources

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I've looked around for a solution, but never got any where by chance.

Basically I need to rip or extract audio files from an PC executable file (.exe), there is Resource Hacker for PC but there isn't an equivalent one for the Mac.

It would be great if there's a decent app that can do what I wish to achieve - so, is there an app out there that can do this?

I'm using OS X 10.7.3.

Answer (score 1):

Try [File Juicer](http://echoone.com/filejuicer/) - it extracts images/text/audio/video from many types of files (see [this list](http://echoone.com/filejuicer/formats/formats) of supported inputs/outputs). The PC executable type (exe) is specifically listed as a supported file type. It's not a free app, but can be used in trial mode.

Answer (score 1):

Try [The Unarchiver](http://unarchiver.c3.cx/).

It is free, either from its website or from [The Mac App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-unarchiver/id425424353?mt=12) and it can extract some files from EXE archives.

If that doesn't work, I would definitely try FileJuicer (which I own and use and love. It can even 'undelete' pictures on your camera card).

Comment: I think it can only extract from self-extracting exe files and some setup files.